# how do I create a dblink connection in postgres that I can keep using

Tags: postgresql

so - I can create a dblink connection - eg

```sql
select * from dblink( 'dbname=whatever host=the_host user=the_user password=my_password', 'select x, y, z from blah')
```

works fine.
I can even make what appears to be a persistent connection

```sql
select * from dblink_connect( 'dev', 'dbname=whatever host=the_host user=the_user password=my_password');

select * from dblink( 'dev', 'select x, y, z from blah' );
```

works fine.
For a while.
And then after a while - if I try to use dev again - it starts telling me "no open connection".   But if I try to run the connect command again, it tells me a connection with that name already exists.

So how do I establish a named connection that I, and others, can just use directly forever afterwards without having to do any sort of connect/disconnect?

Comment: you can use "foreign server" postgres_fdw extension, register server, import schema or create  foreign tables on which you want to run query from remote server. This way you wont need to use dblink and query or even modify those tables as if they where regular local tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give `dblink()` the name of a foreign server, rather than the name of a connection.

```
create server dev foreign data wrapper dblink_fdw options (host 'thehost', dbname 'whatever');
create user mapping for public server dev options (user 'the_user', password 'my_password');
```

Then run your dblink query just as you currently are, using 'dev' as the name.

Note that this will increase the number of connections done, it is just that the system manages them so that you don't need to.  So it is good for convenience, but not for performance.

Comment: thanks - that's exactly what I was looking for - but I can't figure out how to specify the connection - if I put "user" and "password" in options it just says they aren't valid options

Comment: user and password need to go in the "user mapping", and everything else (host, port, and dbname) go in the "server" options.

Comment: awesome thanks - that's exactly what I wanted - and so weird I never would have found it - now I can create dblinks that are available to everyone!

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-connect.html) says:

> The connection will persist until closed or until the database session is ended.

So I suspect that you are using a connection pool, and

1. you may get a different database session for each transaction (but the dblink connection is open in only one of them)
2. the connection pool may close the backend connections after a while, thereby also closing the dblink connection

If you want to use a feature like dblink, where sessions outlive the duration of a transaction, you need session level pooling.

Comment: but we have another database, not setup by me - that has a connection to another database - and anyone can just login and do a dblink( ...) query with that connection name at any time - we have jobs and views all over the place that use it.   - I'm trying to work out how that was achieved - they created it in some gui tool, and I'm trying to work out how to do it in sql.   I expect it's something like create server... - but I can't figure it out

Comment: Yes, you will have to figure that out before you can be certain why exactly you are experiencing the problem.

Comment: @DarrenOakey  What does this other server you can use connections from return for `select * from dblink_get_connections();`?  How about for `\des`?